# Pandas conditional concatenate of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

This question is an extension of [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column/39224761#39224761)

Given the below dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df["note"]="old note"
```

I need to update A and note columns when A>B. This is what I tried:

```
df.loc[df.A>df.B, "note"]="A was: "+str(df.A)
df.loc[df.A>df.B, "A"]=df.B
```

and

```
df["note"]=np.where(df.A>df.B, "A was: "+str(df["A"]), df["note"])
df.loc[df.A>5, "A"]=df.B
```

the note column does not come out clean, it concatenates the entire A column in a single cell, while I would like to keep only the value of the same row. could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Here is problem with casting column to strings, use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df.loc[df.A>df.B, "note"]="A was: "+df.A.astype(str)
```